# Port 4567 open on router to 'tram' traffic...Should I worry?

Tags: router, internet, port

When I do a port scan on my router (`nmap 192.168.0.1`) the result is:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
4567/tcp open  tram
```

Everything pretty much looks normal except for the last one, the `tram` service on port 4567.  What is this?  Is it something I should be worried about?  I've found a few references online talking about it being a Verizon thing, for updating firmware etc.  But my ISP is Century Link.  The router is an Actiontec C1000A VDSL.

Using [Shields Up!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) to probe my router, I have found that port 4567 is indeed open to the outside world.

Does anyone here know what the "tram" service is?

[image: port 4567 open]

Comment: This is an actiontec thing, not an ISP thing - it is common to Actiontec routers and is indeed for firmware updates.  If you are concerned, then it is best to run this from an external site, to the public IP of the router.